# 'Falcon' or 'Fall-con'

Tags: pronunciation

I'd appreciate a native speaker's opinion on this.

[Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/falcon) list both pronunciations to be correct.

> **falcon**
>
> Pronunciation: BrE /ˈfɔːlkən/  ; NAmE /ˈfælkən/

However, I have heard 'fall-con' only in old movies (The Maltese Falcon/ The Millennium Falcon, both American movies), never in anything recent.

My questions:

- Am I likely to be made fun of in (your country) if I call it Fall-con, or is it still pronounced that way?
- Are there any particular connotations attached with the 'Fall-con' pronunciation. Does it sound too highbrow?

EDIT: At Peter Shor's suggestion, let's throw 'fawcon'[(ˈfɔː(l)k(ə)n)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/falcon) into the mix.

Comment: And you don't even mention the British pronunciation [*fawcon*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/falcon).

Comment: @PeterShor: The 'L' is optional? Jeez! Didn't know that.

Comment: I've certainly heard both pronunciations, though the first is more common, by maybe 5 to 1.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction - I'd think you'd have figured out by now that the L is *always* optional.

Comment: The American pronunciation is definitely /ˈfælkən/ and has been my entire life (my father was a falconer). I don't know why all these Hollywood movie are pronouncing it British. *The Maltese Falcon* was made at a time when actors spoke with mid-Atlantic accents (halfway between American and British), and maybe *The Millennium Falcon*'s pronunciation is an homage to *The Maltese Falcon*.

Comment: 'fawcon' is a Cockney pronunciation, but if you're going to get that detailed, there are many other versions (see my comment about consonants).  Certain comically upper-class RP speakers may sound like they're not pronouncing the 'l', but they're just speaking with their lower jaw pushed so far back that you don't hear it...

Comment: @bobtato: "fawcon" may be a Cockney pronunciation but that doesn't make it only a Cockney pronunciation. The "l" being completely vocalized to "w" is historical and dates back to Middle English. The "l" has been restored for most modern speakers, as in similar words like "fault", but not all, and I haven't heard of any evidence that it went extinct in RP while that dialect was still alive.

Comment: The pronunciation in *Maltese Falcon* repeats the sound in *Maltese*. Think how much less memorable and how much uglier it would sound otherwise.

Comment: @sumelic: it's not just Cockney. John Walker's *Principles of English Pronunciation*, from 1816, contained the upper-class pronunciations. And he says the *'l'* is silent in *falcon*.

Comment: @bobtato There are many speakers of RP—I am one of them—who phonotactically do not have tautosyllabic /ɒlk/ or /ɔlk/ at all, mandatorily deleting the /l/. That’s not a restriction to Cockney (or even Estuary), nor to “comically upper-class” speakers. _Falcon_ and _forken_ are exact, precise, complete homophones to me, and to many others. (This is different to the Cockney l-vocalisation, which is generic to [ɫ]; unlike Cockneys, for instance, many speakers like me who have no /l/ in _falcon_ do have an [ɫ] in _whelp_, _alp_, _bulk_, _milk_, etc.)

Comment: I pronounce it /ˈfɒlk(ə)n/, which is also the first-listed pronunciation at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/falcon - and one which strangely the OP hasn't added to their post, even though they copied Oxford's second-listed option /ˈfɔː(l)k(ə)n/ from the same source.  However, /fælk(ə)n/ is quite a common pronunciation in BrE too (and is listed by Collins). /ˈfɔː(l)k(ə)n/ would probably strike some people as a bit posh and a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: Tower, this is flight 586. We have a fawcon problem.

Comment: Growing up in Michigan, I had a neighbor whose dog's name was Falcon, which was funny because in accent in the area of Michigan I'm from, every time they called their dog, it sounded like they were saying the F-word such that it sounded like his name was F*cking. That brings me to my point-- The answer to your question depends entirely on a person's accent, for the two pronunciations you cite as being listed in the dictionary aren't even all of the possible ways to pronounce it but just the two most common, depending on accent.

Comment: Also, this question is like a hotly debated issue in a town I used to live in named Albany. Half of the residents said the "al" at the beginning like the first name Al and the other half like the word "all," which is exactly what you're asking regarding the word "falcon." No resolution ever came, though, because ne'er the twain would meet, each sticking to their way being the right way, meaning the issue may even be more complex than the speaker's given accent as it was and is mostly people from the same place with the same accent who were and are split on the right way to say the "al."

Comment: @PeterShor So true. Since the OP didn't mention it, I was going to, but you did, so I didn't have to. I can't remember if it was the BBC show In the Loop or its movie spin-off In the Thick of It, but this question and the comments remind me of all the confusion that resulted from how Brits often pronounce "wall" and "war" identically and how that led an MP discussing a "wall" to be fixed on a council estate getting overheard by others as "war" and nearly led Britain to go to "war." It was a dark comedy, to be sure. The other memorable thing about those shows is how deftly Peter Capaldi swears.

Comment: @PeterShor: Didn't know that (fawcon without the l sound). Gives me another thought about "dapple dawn-drawn falcon". BTW, what about "dauphin" - is there a British pronunciation of that that also uses the "aw" sound? [The Windhover](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44402/the-windhover): *"I caught this morning morning's minion, kingdom of daylight's dauphin, dapple-dawn-drawn Falcon..."*

Comment: @Drew: Nice observation! And yes, dictionaries say that *dauphin* can be pronounced with an "aw" (/ɔ/ in IPA) sound.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK, it is nominally fall-con, but in practice that means that people with non-RP (received pronunciation) dialects pronounce it in their corresponding versions-- fælkən in the North of England, falkən in the Southwest, etc.  Dictionaries list only one pronunciation for British English, and in the past other dialects were essentially considered "wrong".  The modern view is that you're saying it right as long as your pronunciation transposes into the dictionary form, based on your dialect.

However, it's not uncommon for UK speakers to pronounce proper nouns, or words they only hear from speakers of other dialects, in ways that are not the default for their dialect.  For example, an English person who generally says *fɔlkən* might well refer to an F-15 *Falkən.*  There's quite a lot of latitude in UK vowel sounds.

(Consonants are a different story; many regional variations, like London's /θ/ → /f/ and Newcastle's /t/ → /ʔ/, are still often looked down upon)

Comment: Where is the source for it being "nominally fall-con" in the UK?  Or have you just swallowed that uncritically from the OP's question? Oxford (ODO, UK edition) gives that pronunciation as only one possibility among several (and not even its first); Cambridge doesn't give that pronunciation at all; Collins gives it but alongside an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you mean F-16 Fighting Falcon; F-15's nickname is Eagle.

Answer (score 4):

No one will bat an eye if you refer to the bird with either pronunciation, but the Ford automobile is never ***FALL-con***. (US)

Answer (score 3):

The word **falcon**, when it first appeared in Middle English, was spelt and pronounced *l*-lessly: *faucon, faukun, faucoun*.  The *l* was added in the 15th century to accord with Latin, and presumably the pronunciation changed (for some speakers at least) subsequently.  *Faucon* is still the word in modern French, and is pronounced /fokɔ̃/.

The OED offers two pronunciations, the traditional RP pronunciations: /ˈfɔːlkən/ (roughly "fawlken" for those who haven't bothered to learn the IPA) and /ˈfɔːk(ə)n/ ("fawken").

However, the OED's entry hasn't been "fully" updated since it was written in the 19th century, and more recent British dictionaries offer different pronunciations:

- **[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/falcon)** (BrE version) has /ˈfɒlk(ə)n/ ("folken" with an English, not American, short "o") and /ˈfɔː(l)k(ə)n/ (shorthand for the two variants given in the OED)
- **[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/falcon)** (BrE version) has /ˈfɒlkən/ ("folken" again)
- **[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/falcon)** has /fɔːlkən/ ("fawlken") and /fælkən/ ("falken" with the short "a" of "cat")

American dictionaries give these pronunciations:

- **[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falcon)** and **[American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=falcon)** both offer non-IPA transcriptions equivalent to /ˈfælkən/, /ˈfɔ(:)lkən/, and /ˈfɔ(:)kən/
- **Cambridge** (AmE version) has /ˈfælkən, ˈfɔl-/ ("falken" with a short "a", and "fawlken")

It seems a range of pronunciations are possible in both countries, although all American sources put /ˈfæl·kən/ first (which is sometimes an indicator that it is the most common or most widely accepted option, although this isn't infallible), while British sources vary.

Even though all the pronunciations are used and heard, this doesn't mean all will be equally accepted by everyone.  At least in Britain, it's not entirely unknown for people to make fun of (or make secret judgements about) others' pronunciations if they are unfamiliar with them or if they think they sound too "posh" or too "common" or too northern or too southern.

Answer (score 2):

A native American born before WWII, I have always pronounced 'falcon' FALL-k'n and that was how I had always heard it pronounced too, until Ford Motors introduced the Falcon, which Ford ads pronounced FAL-k'n. Chevrolet introduced a car spelled 'Vega' which Chevrolet ads called 'VEE-g'(u)h'. Must be a Detroit thing.

Maybe Falcon's 1st pronunciation struck some as too highbrow, but then too some also pronounce Venezuela as 'Ven-eh-ZOO-la'.

Are reasonable people to let ignoramuses try to misinform everybody with claims of how real people really do everything? Such turkeys become instant experts with facts and usages they mislearned only shortly before.

How about informed people?

In my stab at laying out Falcon's pronunciation a schwa should be the 2nd and 4th syllables' vowel sound. My computer does not type schwas.

Comment: This is actually a question and answer page, not a discussion page. Each answer that you post in an answer box is expected to stand alone as an answer to the question at the top. An answer should answer the question comprehensively as an expert would answer it, with explanation, context, and supporting facts that show that it is right. Personal opinions, speculation, anecdotes, and general discussion are welcome in [chat].

Comment: Am I missing anything? My answer responded to a request for a native speaker's opinion.     I am an American native speaker.  Doesn't my answer give do that?    Telling whether my answer was in or out, is impossible from what came back.

Answer (score 0):

American here, born in 1964.  I was raised to say FALL-con and still do.  I've noticed the other pronunciation becoming more common, but it's less aesthetic so I stick with what my momma taught me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I likely to be made fun of in (your country) if I call it Fall-con, or is it still pronounced that way?

No. It will be attributed to your foreign accent.

> Are there any particular connotations attached with the 'Fall-con' pronunciation. Does it sound too highbrow?

"Fall-con" is "RP" and associated with the middle classes. At one time it might have been common, but now it is dated and "highbrow" as you say.

I'm a birdwatcher and in BE and my (originally) East Midlands accent, I pronounce it somewhere between /'fælkn/ and /'fɔlkn/ as do other birdwatchers here in southern England regardless of social status.